# Release new object after action

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, release, retain

In my game scene I spawn balls from a ball class that move randomly with the MoveBy action. My question is, how do I release ball after the MoveTo action is over? See my code below:

```
//GameScene class
 ...

 Ball *ball = new Ball(); //<----need to release this after action is over
 ball->spawnBall(this); 

 ...


//Ball class
 ...

void Ball::spawnBall(cocos2d::Layer *layer){

ball = Sprite::create();
layer->addChild(ball);
auto action = Sequence::create(MoveBy::create(...)), RemoveSelf::create(),   null);
ball->runAction(action);

}
```

I want to have control of it's memory (heap) because I found using an automatic release (stack):

```
  Ball ball;
  ball.spawnBall(this);
```

Some of the balls would stop randomly. I am thinking they are overwriting eachothers memory when spawned.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know if you create it via `create` method it should automatically release (via `autorelease`) if you call `release` after you are done using it (because retain count goes to 0) ?

Comment: Yeah I know the create() method automatically releases. But I am not sure if this solves my problem. Could you provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your stack variable is going out of scope if `runAction` is async call:

```
int GameScene::func()
{
 Ball ball;
 ball.spawnBall(this); 
 return 0; //ball is automatically deleted here
}
```

You should be able to

```
int GameScene::func()
{
 Ball *ball = Ball::create(); //dont use new here, use create() function here and autorelease
 ball.spawnBall(this); 
 //autorelease here
 return 0;
}
```

I highly recommend reading through [Memory deallocation in Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/reference_count_and_autoreleasepool_in_cocos2d-x)

Comment: I am getting: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. FYI am calling this func repeatedly to display many balls on the screen. Also I am using a void instead of an int, so I had to type cast it as (Ball*)Ball::create();